# Universal cover and lifts

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $f:Y\to X$ be a universal cover map. By injectivity, if $\gamma$ represents a non-trivial element of $\pi_1(X)$, then any of its lift, say $\bar{\gamma}$, is not a loop. My question is: if $\gamma$ represents a trivial element, why are all of its lifts loops, why the case of the path, which is not a loop, can not happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to a universal cover is a Serre fibration, so you can lift an homotopy $H_t$ wich deforms the loop to a point.

Let $H_t$ be a deformation of the loop $c$ to a point, you have $H_t(0,t)=c(t), H_t(1,u)=p$. You can lift it to $H'_t$, the map $f(H'_t(1,u))=p$. Since $g:u\rightarrow H'_t(1,u)$ is continuous, and there exists an open subset $U$ containing $H'(1,0)$ such that the restriction of  the covering to $U$ is injective, you deduce that $g(u)=H'_t(0,u)$ is constant. You also say that $g$ is a continuous map defined on a connected space whose image is discrete so it is constant.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know why the case of the path, which is not a loop, can not happen.

Comment: Let $H_t$ be a deformation of the loop $c$ to a point, you have $H_t(0,t)=c(t), H_t(1,u)=p$. You can lift it to $H'_t$, the map $f(H'_t(1,u))=p$. Since $g:u\rightarrow H'_t(1,u)$ is continuous, and there exists an open subset $U$ containing $H'(1,0)$ such that the restriction of  the covering to $U$ is injective, you deduce that $H'_t(0,u)$ is constant. You also say that $g$ is a continuous map defined on a connected space whose image is discrete so it is constant.